# How can I keep my sub-divs from moving underneath each other when I resize the window?

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting my divs to behave the way I would like them to. Below is a mock-up of my page. The page looks great, until I make my window smaller. At that point, sub-div B will move underneath sub-div A, which is what I **do not** want.

How do I go about keeping sub-div A and sub-div B in line with each other even when the window size is reduced?

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| div (container)                                              |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
| | div                                                      | |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
|                                                              |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
| | super div                                                | |
| | +------------------------+    +------------------------+ | |
| | | sub-div A - float left |    | sub div-B - float left | | |
| | +------------------------+    +------------------------+ | |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
|                                                              |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
| | div - clear both                                         | |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
|                                                              |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
| | div - clear both                                         | |
| +----------------------------------------------------------+ |
|                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you also provide the html / css for this? Perhaps set up a fiddle to showcase this issue.

Comment: @EliranMalka - Yeah, sorry about that. I have changed my question title to be more reflective of the question I would like to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `float` for the sub-`div`s and by definition that will make them wrap under each other when they cannot fit on the screen. To make sure they stay on the same line, remove the `float` and make them both `display: inline-block` and then on the super `div` add the style `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: That did it, alright. Thank you. However, now sub-div B is in line with, but lower than sub-div A.

Comment: @Brian, are you using percentage widths and margins? Are you using `box-sizing: border-box`? Floats are fine if you're using those. This solution could potentially cause more issues than it solves.

Comment: Fixed it. I made the position relative and vertically aligned both of the sub-modules, and they fell in line with each other.